# How to insert a loop to create items to be passed in

Tags: c#, function, foreach, insert

So I have this function

```
context.IdentifierTypes.AddOrUpdate(
    i => i.Id,
    new IdentifierLookup { Id = 1, IdentifierType = "1")},
    new IdentifierLookup { Id = 2, IdentifierType = "2")},
    new IdentifierLookup { Id = 3, IdentifierType = "3")});
```

These Identifiers are derived from a enum, I do not know how many this enum will take so I would like to put a loop in this function much like this

```
context.IdentifierTypes.AddOrUpdate(
    i => i.Id,

   int j = 1;
   foreach (var identifierType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(IdentifierTypes)))
   {
       new IdentifierLookup { Id = j, IdentifierType = identifierType.toString())},
       j++;
   }
   );
```

How is this done?

Comment: The question is unclear. Without more specifics, it's impossible to know for sure what you are actually trying to do. What is the method signature for `AddOrUpdate()`? What is the declaration of `IdentifierLookup` and `IdentifierTypes`? Why don't you increment `j` in the code you posted? What is the mapping between `Id` and `IdentifierType`? Please provide a good [mcve] that addresses these questions and which shows clearly what you've already tried. Explain precisely what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a lambda method inside the method call or a static method to return array of IdentifierLookup.

```
 context.IdentifierTypes.AddOrUpdate(i=> i.Id, GetLookup());


 private static IdentifierLookups[] GetLookups()
 {
    //loop through the enums create new object and return the array
 }
```